# clear last selected value in JCombobox on selecting another item

Tags: java

I have 8 comboboxes...1st combobox is client and remaining 7 comboboxes depending on it...so if I select A item from client combobox then in user combo I have to get values related to A only and remaining comboboxes also get values related to A only...but here if I select B from client then items related to A should be clear and got items from B only...so how to clear existing items ?

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    try
    {
        String query="select distinct `User_Name`,`Purchaser_Name`,`Product1`,`User_boss`,`Purchaser_boss`,`Sales_Engineer`,`Sales_boss`  from Client where Client_Name = ?";
        PreparedStatement pst=conn.prepareStatement(query);
        pst.setString(1, (String) client.getSelectedItem());
        ResultSet rs=pst.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next())
        {

            user.addItem(rs.getString("User_Name"));
            user.setSelectedItem(null);
            purchase.addItem(rs.getString("Purchaser_Name"));

            prod.addItem(rs.getString("Product1"));

            uboss.addItem(rs.getString("User_boss"));

            pboss.addItem(rs.getString("Purchaser_boss"));

            sengg.addItem(rs.getString("Sales_Engineer"));

            sboss.addItem(rs.getString("Sales_boss"));

//          System.out.println(query);

        }
//      System.out.println(query);


    }
    catch(Exception h)
    {
        h.printStackTrace();
    }    
}
```

Comment: Please, post the code which selects combobox items

Comment: Here i select items only in client combobox...and for that pass variabel client....  pst.setString(1, (String) client.getSelectedItem());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create reference `lastSelectedItem`.
When you make selection ActionEvent is fired and sent to your ActionListener.
In listener call method `getSelectedItem` of `JComboBox` to store it in `lastSelectedItem`.

When you select another item in combobox your listener is fired again and you can use `lastSelectedItem` reference to locate it within jcombobox and clear it.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer but can you please post a code to illustrate this. it will be very help full. I am not sure of how to write ?

Comment: Here is https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#listeners